# Checked item form Array 1, and pass checked item to Array 2, then hide checked item from Array 2 rendered list

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

First, please check this pen I found, the concept is similar to my question, [ReactJS - Baby Name Inspiration](https://codepen.io/simonswiss/pen/memmZN). I hope to make it via Vue.js but sorry I don't know React.

The question I want to ask if the user click the list item from Array 1, I named Array 1 as `animals`, the structure will show below. Then, it will pass the clicked item to Array 2, Array 2 as `wished_pets_list`. If for example `{displayName: "Kitty", value: "cat"}` clicked from `animals` list, `animals` & `wished_pets_list` also stored this object. When the same object in two arrays, the render of `animals` element will hide the object's output in HTML; it also renders to `wished_pets_list` as button. If click `wished_pets_list`'s item button, it will remove the object data from `wished_pets_list`, and can access back on `animals` HTML list. And it can loop again.

The setting of data, default:

```
data: () => ({
    animals: [
        {displayName: "Kitty", value: "cat"},
        {displayName: "Puppy", value: "dog"},
        {displayName: "Chick", value: "bird"},
        {displayName: "Fawn", value: "Deer"},
        {displayName: "Joey", value: "Kangaroo"},
        {displayName: "Piglet", value: "pig"},
        {displayName: "Fry", value: "fish"},
        {displayName: "Polliwog", value: "frog"}
    ],
    wished_pets_list: [],
    wished_pets_list_formatted: []
}),
```

Something I try on make it as HTML:

```
<div v-for="item in wished_pets_list">
    <span @click="removeSelected(item.value)">{{item.displayName}}</span>
</div>

<div class="dropdown-list-container">
    <div class="dropdown-list" v-for="(item, index) in animals">
        <label :for="'givenID' + item.index" @click="pushSelect(item.value)">{{index}}{{item.displayName}}</label>
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="wished_pets_list" :value="{'displayName': item.displayName, 'value': item.value}" :id="givenID' + item.index">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- a hidden text field to submit the formatted as value only -->
<input type="text" v-model="wished_pets_list_formatted" name="anyName" v-show>
```

Two methods I think it should use:

```
methods: {
    removeSelected(value){
        this.wished_pets_list_formatted.push(value);
    },
    pushSelect(value){
        this.wished_pets_list_formatted.splice(value);
    }
},
```

Thanks, if you can, please make a similar codepen or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on @Allkin's answer, and my addition requirement, I tried to make such like Allkin's answer with an ordered list.

> The template:

```
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div class="favourites">
      <h4>Your Shortlist</h4>
      <ul>
        <li class="girl" v-for="(animal, index) in wished_pets_list" @click="removeFromList(index, animal.value, animal.id)">{{animal.displayName}}</li>
      </ul>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(animal, index) in animals" :key="animal.value" class="boy" @click="addToList(index, animal.value, animal.id)" v-show="!animal.checked">{{animal.displayName}}</li>

    </ul>
    <span>wished_pets_list_formatted:</span>
    <div>{{wished_pets_list_formatted}}</div><br><br>
    <span>animals:</span>
    <div>{{animals}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> js:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      org_animal_list: [
        { displayName: "Kitty", value: "cat" },
        { displayName: "Puppy", value: "dog" },
        { displayName: "Chick", value: "bird" },
        { displayName: "Fawn", value: "Deer" },
        { displayName: "Joey", value: "Kangaroo" },
        { displayName: "Piglet", value: "pig" },
        { displayName: "Fry", value: "fish" },
        { displayName: "Polliwog", value: "frog" }
      ],
      animals: null,
      wished_pets_list: [],
      wished_pets_list_formatted: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addToList(index, value, id) {
      console.log("added: " + value);
      this.wished_pets_list.push(this.animals[index]);
      this.wished_pets_list_formatted.push(value);
      this.animals[index].checked = !this.animals[index].checked;
    },
    removeFromList(index, value, id) {
      var self = this;
      this.wished_pets_list.splice(index, 1);
      this.wished_pets_list_formatted.forEach(function(item, index) {
        if (item == value) {
          self.wished_pets_list_formatted.splice(index, 1);
        }
      });
      for (var i = 0; i < this.animals.length; i++) {
        if (self.animals[i].id == id) {
          self.animals[i].checked = !self.animals[i].checked;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  beforeMount: function() {
    this.animals = this.org_animal_list;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.animals.length; i++) {
      this.$set(this.animals[i], "checked", false);
      this.$set(this.animals[i], "id", i);
    }
  }
});
```

I added an original list first, then it will clone before Vue mount. This action allows the developer can use back the original data for other use.

For the full example, please check on [codepen](https://codepen.io/sctw/pen/PBrMrz?editors=1011)

Answer (score 1):

Below is a **implementation of the example codepen in Vue**(didn't included the search part because I think it's irelevant in this case).

> The template:

```
<div id="app">
  <div data-reactroot="">
   <main>
      <div class="favourites">
         <h4>Your Shortlist</h4>
         <ul>
           <li class="girl" v-for="(animal, index) in wished_pets_list" @click="removeFromList(index)">{{animal.displayName}}</li>
         </ul>
         <hr>
      </div>
      <ul>
         <li v-for="(animal, index) in animals" :key="animal.value" class="boy" @click="addToList(index)">{{animal.displayName}}</li>

      </ul>
   </main>
</div>
</div>
```

The javascript part:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
  data () {
    return {
      animals: [
        {displayName: "Kitty", value: "cat"},
        {displayName: "Puppy", value: "dog"},
        {displayName: "Chick", value: "bird"},
        {displayName: "Fawn", value: "Deer"},
        {displayName: "Joey", value: "Kangaroo"},
        {displayName: "Piglet", value: "pig"},
        {displayName: "Fry", value: "fish"},
        {displayName: "Polliwog", value: "frog"}
    ],
    wished_pets_list: [],
    wished_pets_list_formatted: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addToList(index) {
      this.wished_pets_list.push(this.animals[index])
      this.animals.splice(index, 1)
    },
    removeFromList(index) {
      this.animals.push(this.wished_pets_list[index])
      this.wished_pets_list.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }
});
```

For the CSS you can use the one from the codepen example.
[Codepen fork](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QBXdXN)

Comment: but if I want to make the below list don't change the order from init render. I hope to make the order like: Kitty > Puppy > Chick > Fawn > Joey > Piglet > Fry > Polliwog. Because of your example is now when I add to the shortlist, it will remove from below list. When remove from shortlist, it will add back to below list but insert of the end of the below list. I would like to insert back to original order.